# How do I write a batch script to start a process and terminate it after letting it run for about 10 seconds?

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, batch

How do I write a batch script to start a process and terminate it after letting it run for about 10 seconds?

```
@echo off
  start abcd.exe
  [X]
  taskkill /im abcd.exe /f
  exit
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this in a batch file that is universally supported across any machine you try to run it on.

Not sure if you specifically require a batch file, but this VBScript code will run on any Windows computer consistently and it's very simple.

```
For i = 0 to 10
    WScript.Sleep(1000)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual solutions for your [x] are :

```
ping -n 11 localhost > nul 
timeout /t 10 > nul
choice /t 10 /c ü /d ü /n >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Linux (Unix). You didn't specify what your using but it may give you some other ideas in what your using.

```
    Process [Argument]... &   #starts your command in background
    LastPID=$!                #stores the Process ID number as that var
    sleep 10                  #sleeps for 10 seconds
    kill $!                   #kills your background process
```

Comment: The question says "batch script" and is tagged "Windows 8.1". This answer does not appear to be useful.